# How do you ensure only visible items are loaded when using MvvmCross and the MvxListView

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In my project we are calling a REST service for first getting a list of items, and then calling again for getting information about each item.

The problem is that these calls are made in the ViewModel, and here we wont know how many Items are actually visible in the UI. So I end up loading all items, which takes a long time.

Is there a smart way to ensure that only visible items are preloaded in the ViewModel, and then have the rest loaded in an async way, as more items becomes visible?

Thanks

Comment: Load your stuff in smaller chunks.

Comment: You could lazyload your item details when the ui requests a property? Or you could implement some kind of scrolllistener in your view which tells the view model what is visible?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Stuart.
I dont think I can lazyload the details in the property setters, as I wont have a way to await my async calls in this case, but I might give the scrolllistener a try. It would be good for the activity load time if I could postpone the load until user starts scrolling, but maybe hurt the scrolling performance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Cheesebaron.
I tried creating my own ObservableCollection to be able to have the CollectionChanged event fire when I add a range of items instead of on every single one - and this definitely improved performance.

Comment: why do you need to await your async call in the lazyloader? Surely all you need to do is to kick off the loading task (and to make sure you don't try to load it twice a the same time?)

Comment: Good point @Stuart. I tried to kick off a load task when one of the property getters where called. Unfortunately these also get called for items that are not visible, leaving me with a full initial load anyway. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmmm.... I guess it depends on code - it's always better to include some sample code if you can (answerers often run it!). If your list items are dynamically sized (e.g the use `wrap_content` on strings), then the Android `ListView` may have to get the data in order to find out how big to make the lists scroll area.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. And good point about adding sample code - you probably would have nailed my issue right away if I'd done that. 
Turned out that the main reason for my problems was that we were using ScrollViews and LinearLayouts for showing the items, and these does not have the optimizations the `ListView` has. In the end the lazy loading worked perfectly, for the items in my listview.